# Show that $\sinh x + \sin x \geq 2x$.

Tags: calculus

How can to prove that $\sinh x  + \sin x  \geq  2x $ ? 
I am currently trying with derivatives.

Comment: Look at the Maclaurin series. (Also you want $x\ge0$).

Comment: It's only true for $x\geq 0$.

Answer (score 6):

$$f(x):=\sinh(x)+\sin(x)-2x\\f'(x)=\cosh(x)+\cos(x)-2\\f''(x)=\sinh(x)-\sin(x)>0$$

The last one may be seen as

$$\sinh(x)>x>\sin(x)\quad\forall x>0$$

Since $f(0)=f'(0)=0$ and $f''(x)>0$, it follows that $f'(x)$ is increasing, and thus $f(x)$ is increasing.

Answer (score 1):

As Lord Shark the Unknown commented, it is interesting to look at the two Taylor series (which are valid for all $x$)
$$\sin(x)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!} x^{2n+1}$$
$$\sinh(x)= \sum^{\infty}_{n=0} \frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$ So, this all makes
$$\sinh(x)+\sin(x)=2\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{x^{4n-3}}{(4n-3)!}=2x+2\sum^{\infty}_{n=2} \frac{x^{4n-3}}{(4n-3)!}=2x+2\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{x^{4n+1}}{(4n+1)!}$$ BUt, as already pointed in comments, $\sinh(x)+\sin(x)>2x$ is only valid for $x >0$. Otherwise, i would be the opposite.